# Number of shortest paths in a graph

Tags: graph

I need to find the number of all paths between two nodes of a graph by using BFS. I think the answer to my question can be found here:

[How to find the number of different shortest paths between two vertices, in directed graph and with linear-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226251/graph-how-to-find-the-number-of-different-shortest-paths-between-two-vertices)

But I don't quite understand it. Could someone please write the algorithm down in other words so I can understand it better?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let say you need to go from src to dest.

With each vertex x, associate two values count and val, where count is the number of shortest paths from src to x and val is the shortest distance from src to x. Also maintain a visited variable telling whether this is the first time visiting the node or not.

Apply usual BFS algorithm,

```
Initialize u = src
visited[u] = 1, 
val[u] = 0
count[u] = 1
For each child v of u,
    if v is not visited
```

The first time a node is visited, it has only one path from src to now via u, so the shortest path up to v is (1 + shortest path up to u), and number of ways to reach v via shortest path is same as count[u] because say u has 5 ways to reach from source, then only these 5 ways can be extended up to v as v is encountered first time via u, so

```
val[v] = val[u]+1,    
count[v] = count[u], 
visited[v] = 1
    
if v is visited
```

If v is already visited, which means, there exists some other path up to v via some other vertices, then three cases arise:

1. case `val[v] == val[u]+1`

if current val[v] (which is dist up to v via some other path) is equal to val[u]+1, i.e we have equal shortest distances for reaching v using current path through u and the other path up to v, then the shortest distance up to v remains same, but the number of paths increase by number of paths of reaching u.

```
count[v] = count[v]+count[u]
```

2. case `val[v] > val[u]+1`

As we are traversing the nodes using BFS level by level, this case cannot happen: the graph is unweighted, so the first time we set val[v], it is guaranteed that val[v] will already contain the length of the shortest path from src to v.

3. case `val[v] < val[u]+1`

In this case, there is no need to change the values of val[v] and count[v] as this path does not count as a shortest path

Do this algorithm till the BFS is complete.
In the end val[dest] contain the shortest distance from source and count[dest] contain the number of ways from src to dest.

Comment: So, when you are calling the vertex "visited" that means that it is currently in BFS queue? So when it is no longer in the queue I should just skip it whenever I encounter it?

Comment: Also, where do I add to the count value? When I start with zero count in the src vertex there will be zero all the way through.

Comment: No visited means it is visited once. It need not to be in queue at that time.
For count, it was my mistake. Initialize count[src] as 1 as number of ways to reach from src to src is one.

Comment: One more question please. Does it count only the shortest possible paths? Now it seems to me it count all possible paths.

Comment: See the cases above, on case 1, both paths were of equal length then counts were added. In case 2 and case 3, paths are not of equal length, so only the shorter path was kept track of and count[v] was given count of shorter path. For getting total number of ways, just add count of both paths in every case. You need not to maintain val[] array here as it was used to keep track of shortest distance.

Comment: Great! I get it now. I had very stupid mistake there which was entirely my fault. Thank you very much good sir!

Comment: In case 2 (val[v] > val[u]+1). As stated in the answer, we obviously need to update count[v] and val[v], to let's say, count[v]' and val[v]'. Shouldn't we also update any nodes z, for which val[z] is already set to val[v] +1, to val[v]'+1? 

Also, I don't think we should stop as soon as destination is encountered. For example consider the case where multiple edges end at dest, two of which are part of the shortest path.

Comment: Yeah you are right that termination shouldn't be immediately after finding destination. I don't know why I couldn't thought of that then. As per you first problem, you are right again, but since it is BFS, then this case (val[v] > val[u]+1) won't occur as you are going level by level. I think I didn't notice this also that time. Thanks for highlighting the mistakes.