# Shortest paths in graph

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

I've got a problem with a 2-section question:

G=(V,E) is undirected unweighted graph. t,s are nodes in the graph. e=(a,b) is an edge in the graph.

1) Suggest an efficient algorithm that checks if *e* is a part of **all** shortest paths from *s* to *t*.

2) Suggest an efficient algorithm that checks if *e* is a part of **one** of the shortest paths from *s* to *t*.

I've seen in the forum suggestion to solving section 1, by using Dijkstra algorithm twice, once with the given edge and once without. Then you need to compare the results.
However, I didn't managed to figure more efficient way to solve section 2. I guess it is possible, but I don't know how.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actually for an unweighted, undirected graph, you don't need to use Dijkstra, a simple BFS shall serve the purpose**.

Following method checks whether e is a part of **atleast one** shortest path from s to t:

Compute the shortest path from s to e and the shortest path from e to t

If the sum of the lengths of these two paths is equal to the shortest path from s to t, then e is a part of atleast one shortest path from s to t.

```
s -----> e -------> t
```

If you want to know whether e is a part of **exactly one** shortest path from s to t, then in addition, the following link maybe be helpful. It concerns a directed graph, but our undirected graph can be thought of as a directed graph with edge from `u to v` and `v to u`.

[How to find the number of different shortest paths between two vertices, in directed graph and with linear-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226251/graph-how-to-find-the-number-of-different-shortest-paths-between-two-vertices)

Answer (score 0):

Problem 2 should be should be solvable using **one** (modified) pass of Dijkstra's algorithm.

As before, you keep the frontier of the search space in a priority queue, but you also add one more bit of information, which is a flag that denotes whether the path that lead to this part of the frontier went through the edge in question.

- Initially, just the vertex `s` is in the queue, and the flag is false.
- The flag is propagated (kept as true) if it was true when popped off the head of queue.
- The flag is set to true for the first time, whenever the edge `e` is traversed (i.e. if you needed to traverse `e` to get to a `v` then when pushing `v` onto the queue, you set the flag to true).

`e` was used if when your target, `t` is popped from the stack, its flag is set to true.